# PHP object attributes not outputting properly

Tags: php, oop

I have created a basic PHP Book class which is supposed to print out the $title, $author and $pages. My code however is printing out $pages 3 times instead, any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
<?php
    class Book{
        var $title;
        var $author;
        var $pages;
    }

    $book1 = new Book();
    $book1 -> $title = "Oliver Twist";
    $book1 -> $author = "Charles Dickens";
    $book1 -> $pages = 373;

    echo $book1 -> $title;
    echo $book1 -> $author;
    echo $book1 -> $pages;
?>
```

Expected Output: Oliver TwistCharles Dickens373

Actual Output: 400400400

Comment: Your question is not enough clear. Please, share your code and outputs here.

Comment: Thanks, I've revised the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove $

```
   class Book{
        var $title;
        var $author;
        var $pages;
    }

    $book1 = new Book();
    $book1->title = "Oliver Twist";
    $book1->author = "Charles Dickens";
    $book1->pages = 373;

    echo $book1->title;
    echo $book1 ->author;
    echo $book1 ->pages;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to prefix a $ whenever you access a class property using the object of that class. just remove the $ from the properties you are assigning the values to.

Your code:

```
$book1 = new Book(); 
$book1->title = "Oliver Twist"; 
$book1->author = "Charles Dickens";
$book1->pages = 373;
```

Correct way to accessing the properties of a class is:

```
$object = new yourClass();
$object->classProperty = 'value';
```

Comment: Thank you very much Pramod. I had internalized the idea that the $ prefix is needed everytime when referencing a variable so never considered Class Properties to be different. Thanks again.